# Error connecting to Raspberry Pi 2 using xrdp

Tags: pi-2, connection, fedora, xrdp

I have Fedora 28 MATE installed on a Raspberry Pi 2.  I have xrdp installed and started/enabled on the pi, and have opened port 3389/tcp in the default firewalld zone.  I am trying to connect to the pi from a Mac using Microsoft Remote Desktop version 10.2.1, but keep getting the following error:

```
Your session ended because of a data encryption error. 
If this keeps happening, contact your network administrator for assistance.

Error code: 0x407
```

This is the first time I've seen this error and can't seem to figure out what's going on.  The initial connection showed the self-signed certificate, then the RDP agent goes full screen, sits there for about 10 seconds, then the error message appears and the session closes.

I have a RHEL box with the same setup working fine from my mac, a Fedora box also working fine, so I'm thinking this might be something specific to the pi, but who knows?

The xrdp.log appears to show the connection working, then abruptly stopping:

```
[20180829-09:56:45] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET connection received from 192.168.1.104 port 50007
[20180829-09:56:46] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET 192.168.1.3:3389)
[20180829-09:56:46] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:3389)
[20180829-09:56:46] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20180829-09:56:46] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20180829-09:56:46] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
[20180829-09:56:46] [DEBUG] TLSv1.1 enabled
[20180829-09:56:46] [DEBUG] TLSv1 enabled
[20180829-09:56:46] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
[20180829-09:56:46] [INFO ] connected client computer name: MYMBP.local
[20180829-09:56:46] [INFO ] TLS connection established from 192.168.1.104 port 50007: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
[20180829-09:56:46] [DEBUG] xrdp_00001469_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
[20180829-09:56:46] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000409.ini
[20180829-09:56:46] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000409 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20180829-09:56:46] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
[20180829-09:56:46] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20180829-09:56:46] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20180829-09:56:46] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20180829-09:56:47] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 10
[20180829-09:56:47] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC started connecting
[20180829-09:56:47] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC connecting to 127.0.0.1 5910
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC tcp connected
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC security level is 2 (1 = none, 2 = standard)
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC password ok
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC sending share flag
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC receiving server init
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC receiving pixel format
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC receiving name length
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC receiving name
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC sending pixel format
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC sending encodings
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC sending framebuffer update request
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC sending cursor
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC connection complete, connected ok
[20180829-09:56:49] [INFO ] The following channel is allowed: rdpdr (0)
[20180829-09:56:49] [INFO ] The following channel is allowed: rdpsnd (1)
[20180829-09:56:49] [INFO ] The following channel is allowed: cliprdr (2)
[20180829-09:56:49] [INFO ] The following channel is allowed: drdynvc (3)
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] The allow channel list now initialized for this session
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connected ok
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: chansrv connect successful
[20180829-09:56:49] [DEBUG] Closed socket 18 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:55160)
[20180829-09:56:50] [DEBUG] VNC got clip data
[20180829-09:56:50] [DEBUG] VNC got clip data
[20180829-09:56:52] [DEBUG] Closed socket 20 (AF_UNIX)
[20180829-09:56:52] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET 192.168.1.3:3389)
[20180829-09:56:52] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20180829-09:56:52] [DEBUG] VNC mod_exit
[20180829-09:56:52] [DEBUG] Closed socket 19 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:35038)
```

And the xrdp-sesman.log looks like the connection works, then stops:

```
[20180829-09:56:46] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 55160
[20180829-09:56:47] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username *username*, ip 192.168.1.104:50007 - socket: 12
[20180829-09:56:47] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
[20180829-09:56:47] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:5910)
[20180829-09:56:47] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6010)
[20180829-09:56:47] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6210)
[20180829-09:56:47] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180829-09:56:47] [INFO ] calling auth_start_session from pid 5229
[20180829-09:56:47] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180829-09:56:47] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20180829-09:56:47] [INFO ] Xvnc :10 -auth .Xauthority -geometry 1280x800 -depth 32 -rfbauth /home/*user*/.vnc/sesman_passwd-*user*@MYMBP:10 -bs -nolisten tcp -localhost -dpi 96
[20180829-09:56:48] [CORE ] waiting for window manager (pid 5230) to exit
[20180829-09:56:52] [CORE ] window manager (pid 5230) did exit, cleaning up session
[20180829-09:56:52] [INFO ] calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 5229
[20180829-09:56:52] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets:
[20180829-09:56:52] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_chansrv_audio_out_socket_10
[20180829-09:56:52] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_chansrv_audio_in_socket_10
[20180829-09:56:52] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /tmp/.xrdp/xrdpapi_10
[20180829-09:56:52] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username *username*, display :10.0, session_pid 5229, ip 192.168.1.104:50007 - socket: 12
```

Some things I've checked based on recommendations from research:

-Date and time are correct on pi

-xrdp service has been restarted

-firewalld rules have been reloaded

-problem still persists

Any advice?

Comment: I'm starting to think the gen 2 pi just might not have enough processing power to handle xrdp and MATE F28.  I increased the session delay time in xrdp.ini from ms=1000 to ms=10000 and now an xrdp window is partially drawn (but broken and incomplete). Will investigate further.

Comment: based on this bugzilla report, it appears xrdp might just be broken with MATE and F28

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1575792